# Issue while assigning values to groovy class getting GroovyCastException

Tags: java, groovy

Error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'maitadmin' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'com.student.marks'
```

Below is the code

```
       public Marks getMarks(Map otherParams){
        Marks marks= new Marks();
        marks.user=otherParams.user;
        marks.id=otherParams.id;
        return marks;
        }
```

Caller method

```
Marks marks= getMarks(otherParams);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax was wrong Changed to below:-

```
     public Marks getMarks(Map otherParams){
      Marks marks= new Marks();
      marks.user=otherParams.get("user");
      marks.id=otherParamsget("id");
     return marks;
    }
```